# apt-get install can't find pinned versions within Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, version

During the building of a simple Dockerfile, the pinned version of `apt-get install` is never found and gives me the following output:

```sh
E: Unable to locate package ruby1.9.1-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ruby1.9.1-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby1.9.1-dev'
E: Version '1.1.*' for 's3cmd' was not found
```

I am working according to the dockerfile best practices: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Within there you can find a Dockerfile which has all apt-get recommendations within it:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    aufs-tools \
    automake \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    dpkg-sig \
    libcap-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    mercurial \
    reprepro \
    ruby1.9.1 \
    ruby1.9.1-dev \
    s3cmd=1.1.* \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I am running the docker build with:

`docker build .`

I haven't' found a solution to pin the versions in another way with `apt-get install`. Can someone recommend me how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ruby1.9.1` and `ruby1.9.1-dev` are not available for `ubuntu:18.04`.
You can find here the [list of supported packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) by ubuntu version.

You can also read this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093390/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-ruby1-9-1ruby1-9-1-full-rubygems1-9-1-ruby1-9-1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works if I am using exactly using the version within the list of supported packages or a version with a placeholder. In the case of s3cmd I can use s3cmd=2.0.1-2 or s3cmd=2.0.*

However what if in a year I am using the same Dockerfile to build an image and the version switched to lets say 3.0.0, s3cmd=3.0.0, how can I be sure that it is still executable without interruptions?

Anyway thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: _However what if in a year I am using the same Dockerfile to build an image and the version switched_. Generally all the package version are always available for specific OS (Ubuntu) if a package add a new version the old is still available. You have only to sync between your dev environment and the Dockerfile

Comment: Perfect, thank you Max, I appreciate your answers a lot.

Comment: glad to help you. mark as the answer if you can